# How to write a subquery refactoring WITH clause using Zend framework?

Tags: sql, oracle, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-select

I want to use the `WITH` syntax inside the SQL query in Zend framework, the SQL looks like this:

```
WITH t AS
(SELECT item_id, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY some_criteria DESC) rn
   FROM orders)
SELECT t2.rn, t2.item_id
  FROM t t1 JOIN t t2 ON (t2.rn > t1.rn)
 WHERE t1.item_id = 145;
```

How can I do so in Zend Framework? with `Zend_Db_Select`? Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

With Zend_Db_Select you can't do it in beautiful way, so I suggest you to use simple query:

```
$q = "WITH t ..."
$db->fetchAll($q);
```

Answer (score 0):

I quote-

> Using **Zend_Db_Select** is not mandatory. For very simple SELECT queries,
>   it is usually simpler to specify the entire SQL query as a string and
>   execute it using Adapter methods like **query()** or **fetchAll()**. Using
>   Zend_Db_Select is helpful if you need to assemble a SELECT query
>   procedurally, or based on conditional logic in your application.

So you can try this

```
$wthselect = 'WITH t AS
          (SELECT item_id, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY some_criteria DESC) rn
              FROM orders)
         SELECT t2.rn, t2.item_id
           FROM t t1 JOIN t t2 ON (t2.rn > t1.rn)
           WHERE t1.item_id = 145';

$stmt = $select->query($wthselect);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Zend_Db_Select` is usefull if the query is somewhat complicated, with parameters and logic included in your application, as already quoted on another answer. Check this link on the [official Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html) for detailed description of this insctruction.

Also check [this useful link](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/too-bad-there-s-no-select-gt-fromString-SQL-td3466006.html) from the Zend Framework community, specially [this post](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/too-bad-there-s-no-select-fromString-SQL-tp3466006p3466211.html). It clearly shows that for small and non complicated queries, as the one you posted, is simpler to use the `fetchAll()` or `query()` instructions.

So, my advice, use the `fetchAll()` or `query()` for your case.